# MLA citation style citing two works by the same author

Tags: citing, mla-style

I have been trying to find an answer to this question for days now. Can the following be right?

bib:

```
 \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@book{Dilthey81, 
   Address = {Frankfurt am Main}, 
   Author = {Dilthey, Wilhelm}, 
   Date-Added = {2017-02-02 22:23:04 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2017-02-02 22:25:14 +0000}, 
   Publisher = {Suhrkamp}, 
   Title = {{Der Aufbau der geschichtlichen Welt in den Geisteswissenschaften}}, 
   Year = {[1910] 1981}} 
} 
@book{Dilthey90, 
   Address = {G{\"o}tting}, 
   Author = {Dilthey, Wilhelm}, 
   Date-Added = {2017-02-02 22:13:38 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2017-02-03 11:03:37 +0000}, 
   Edition = {Gesammelte Schriften. Band 1}, 
   Publisher = {Vandenhoeck \& Ruprecht}, 
   Title = {{Einleitung in die Geisteswissenschaft: Versuch einer Grundlegung f{\"u}r das Studium der Gesellschaft und der Geschichte}}, 
   Year = {[1883] 1990}} 
} 
@book{Gadamer04, 
   Address = {London/New York et. al.}, 
   Author = {Gadamer, Hans-Georg}, 
   Date-Added = {2017-02-02 22:26:11 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2017-02-02 22:27:20 +0000}, 
   Publisher = {Bloomsbury Publishing}, 
   Title = {{Truth and Method}}, 
   Year = {[1960] 2004}} 
} 
\end{filecontents}
```

main:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,BCOR=3mm,12pt,titlepage]{scrreprt} 
\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc} 


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 


\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[maxlevel=3,autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes} 

\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans} 
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{\jobname.bib} 

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parencites}[\mkbibparens]{\parencite}{\multicitedelim}



\begin{document} 

\parencites[cf.][]{Dilthey81}[]{Dilthey90}[]{Gadamer04} 

\end{document}
```

I know I am using the MLA style, but I couldn't find a reference for the case when you cite two works by the same author. It just looks so strange.

Comment: Is this really a LaTeX question or simply a question about what the MLA style requires? If it's the latter, I think this isn't the place to ask (not to mention that there are relatively few MLA style users here, I suspect.)

Comment: I would like to know if that's really MLA style and if I could somehow "suppress" the output. It looks so strange when you see both title in the main body of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your output looks so weird is because the full title appears, but in author-title type citation schemes such as MLA, it is usual to use a shortened version of the title for citation purposes.  To do this, you need to add a `shorttitle` field to your `bib` entries for these works.

Also, your `year` fields are incorrect since you've included the original publication date  `[ ... ]` within the year field. This is incorrect. Instead, you should use the `origdate` field.  The `biblatex-mla` style will then format the dates correctly in the bibliography.

Here's your full examples with the relevant fields added to your `.bib` entries.

```
 \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@book{Dilthey81, 
   Address = {Frankfurt am Main}, 
   Author = {Dilthey, Wilhelm}, 
   Date-Added = {2017-02-02 22:23:04 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2017-02-02 22:25:14 +0000}, 
   Publisher = {Suhrkamp}, 
   Title = {{Der Aufbau der geschichtlichen Welt in den Geisteswissenschaften}}, 
   Shorttitle = {Aufbau},
   Origdate = {1910},
   Year = {1981} 
} 
@book{Dilthey90, 
   Address = {G{\"o}tting}, 
   Author = {Dilthey, Wilhelm}, 
   Date-Added = {2017-02-02 22:13:38 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2017-02-03 11:03:37 +0000}, 
   Edition = {Gesammelte Schriften. Band 1}, 
   Publisher = {Vandenhoeck \& Ruprecht}, 
   Title = {{Einleitung in die Geisteswissenschaft: Versuch einer Grundlegung f{\"u}r das Studium der Gesellschaft und der Geschichte}},
   Shorttitle={Einleitung},
   Origdate={1883},
   Year = {1990} 
} 
@book{Gadamer04, 
   Address = {London/New York et. al.}, 
   Author = {Gadamer, Hans-Georg}, 
   Date-Added = {2017-02-02 22:26:11 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2017-02-02 22:27:20 +0000}, 
   Publisher = {Bloomsbury Publishing}, 
   Title = {{Truth and Method}},
   Origdate = {1960},
   Year = {2004} 
} 
\end{filecontents} 
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,BCOR=3mm,12pt,titlepage]{scrartcl} 
\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc} 


\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[maxlevel=3,autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes} 




\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex} 
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parencites}[\mkbibparens]{\parencite}{\multicitedelim}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document} 
\parencites[cf.][]{Dilthey81}[]{Dilthey90}[]{Gadamer04} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!